# Rails: temporarily disable user registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

With a basic `User` registration function, (e.g. following [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?view=asciicast),) what's the best way to temporarily enable/disable it in production? I'd like a simple on/off switch of some sort--the db console is ok with me.

Comment: Don't believe there is an out-of-the-box thing for this. If you're writing custom code you'd have to write that part as well. But I guess a good option would be to add a filter to your controller(s), something like `require_logged_in_user`, which you can then easily disable by commenting it out.

Comment: Yeah, I doubt that there's anything out-of-the-box. I was actually thinking about enabling/disabling the actual sign-up function of my `User` controller and rendering an alternate view. But I'm not sure if that would be a typical way of doing it... I assume I'd need some sort of model that retains whether signup is enabled or not?

Comment: You can always put a condition after the before_action and call a method that confirms if you want to require auth.  The condition in the method could be based on an env variable, config variable or db value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve it.

**1. Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :sessions if Rails.env.development?
```

Pretty basic but works - you can use the `env` object to determine which type of environment you're currently running, permitting or denying routes accordingly.

---

**2. Controller-Level**

Next you have controller-level functionality.

This would give you the ability to post feedback like this:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def create
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sorry, you cannot register" if Rails.env.production?
   end
end
```

---

**3. Model-Level**

Finally, model level.

This would be connected to your database.

You could do something like this:

```
#app/models/option.rb
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | name | value | created_at | updated_at
   scope :prod_sessions, -> { find_by(name: "prod_sessions").pluck(:value) }
end
```

In your *options* table, you could then add the following record:

```
name: "prod_sessions"
value: 0
```

This way, you'll be able to call the following:

```
if Option.prod_sessions?
   #do something here
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. The last option is exactly what I was imagining. Is that a common solution?

Comment: Wordpress uses it :) https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options

Comment: Awesome! That's proof enough for me. Thanks!